# Closedness of set of functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $K$ be a non-empty, proper, and closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and equip $C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ with the compact-open topology.  Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow K$ be a continuous surjection.  Is the subset
$$
\left\{g \in C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}): g=h\circ f , \, h \in C(K,\mathbb{R})\right\}
$$
a proper closed subset of $C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$.  Intuitively it seems clear, but I have no idea how to proceed..

Comment: Actually not I want to only consider the pre-composition of every function in $C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ by $f$.  (Since otherwise there my be more continuous functions in $C(K,\mathbb{R})$ that I don't want)

Comment: I don't think it matters a thing, as every function in $C(K,\Bbb R)$ has an extension to $\Bbb R^d$. The compositions of these are the same.

Comment: Ah!  you're right by Tietze extension theorem?! Good point.

Comment: A result by McCoy and Ntantu from 1988 (their lecture notes on function spaces) says that this subset is closed in the compact open topology if $f$ is compact-covering (every compact subset of $K$ is contained in the image of a compact subset of $\Bbb R^d$) and a quotient map. Nothing about necessity, just sufficiency. For the pointwise topology $f$ has to be a $\Bbb R$-quotient map for this to hold (there we have iff)